# vue3 reactivity inside a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I was trying to have a reactive property in a class so this is what I did :

```
Class B{
  index = ref(-1);

  canUndo: ComputedRef<boolean>;

  canRedo: ComputedRef<boolean>;

  constructor(private max: number) {
    this.canUndo = computed(() => {
      return this.index.value > -1;
    });
    this.canRedo = computed(() => {
      const { length } = this.items;
      return length > 0 && this.index.value < length - 1;
    });
  }

  undo() {
    console.log(this.canUndo); // -> true
    console.log(this.canUndo.value); // -> undefined
    if (!this.canUndo.value) return false;

    console.log(this.index); // -> 1
    this.index.value -= 1;
    return this.items.slice(0, this.index.value + 1);
  }
  
}

// this is how I use it
class A{
  b:B;

  undo(){ this.b.undo() }
}

export default defineComponent({
  setup(){
    const a= ref<A>();

    function initA() {
      a.value = new A();
    }

    return { a };
  }
});
```

```html
<BaseButton
        :disabled="!a.b.canUndo"
        color="light" size="sm" @click="a.undo()"
        start-icon="undo"></BaseButton>
```

I was expecting this to work but I am seeing a weird behavior!
`this.canUndo` is a `boolean` where I expected to be `ComputedRef<boolean>` and therefore `this.canUndo.value` is `undefined`!

same goes for `this.index`?!?

Why? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

UPDATE based on @tony19's answer:
The component is actually like this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  setup(){
    const elRef = ref<HTMLElement>();
    const a = ref<A>();

    function initA() {
      a.value = new A(elRef);
    }

    onMounted(initA);

    return { a };
  }
});
```

I can't do any of the suggested workarounds Because I need a element ref to actually initiate the class, so it needs to be initiated in `onMounted` hook.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to how `ref`s are automatically unwrapped in the template, [as noted in `setup()` docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#setup). That seems to include unwrapping the `ref`s in the class's methods.

A workaround is to expose the original instance to the template. It doesn't need to be a `ref` unless you plan on changing its value (e.g., to a new instance of `A`):

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    //const a = ref<A>(new A())
    const a = new A()

    return { a }
  }
})
```

If you actually need to keep a `ref`, you could expose the `ref` along with the original:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const rawA = new A()
    const a = ref<A>(rawA)

    return { a, rawA }
  }
})
```

Then in your template, use the original for any methods that have `ref`s:

```html
<BaseButton @click="rawA.undo()">
```

Comment: tnx for reply, unfortunately can't do any of these, added more info to post, please check it out, the only reason I am using ref is because of the late initialization of the A class

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with this dilemma of classes and reactivity in vue 3, so I went looking for a solution and found the one in this repository, whoever made it is already on another level.

The idea is to avoid references to computeds with "this", as this element does not get reactivity by the Proxy

Example:

```
interface State {
  example: number
  myComputedProperty: boolean
}

class MyReactiveClass {
    state: State

    constructor() {
        const state = reactive({
          example: 0,
          myComputedProperty: computed(() => state.example === 10),
        });

        this.state = state
    }
}
```

Learned from:

https://github.com/tetsuharuohzeki/WebKit/blob/23ed9c160c93c7471d3f5176c30cfbc407055cb4/PerformanceTests/JetStream3/proxy/vue-benchmark.js#L44C1-L56C2